# Playing flute High notes: role of lip position and one's mood

Tags: flute

I have been practicing bamboo flute for 6 months. I initially got a nice beautiful low notes but the high notes were a problem. After that I changed my finger positions and it affected my sound but i sticked to it. Now I can produce low notes clearly and high notes clear but it is only if I place my flute little tilted inwards. Also I can hear a initial puu sound before I can touch the high register.

I see many videos and tutorials and tried to emulate them. But when I tend to play long sounds particularly high notes, I give too much air and pressure. After that I physically tried and frustrated. If some experienced people can enlighten me about the causes of this and how to overcome , It will be greatly helpful.. I guess it is my lip position and mood that is affecting the tone.

Comment: Get a teacher.  Video tutorials are not an acceptable substitute.  Without observation and coaching you're almost guaranteed to do things wrong and as you've seen, wear yourself out.

Comment: Get more flutes. It could be the flute. Instruments of this type need a lot of air, but some more than others. You probably already know that you need to produce a fast moving, narrow stream of air properly aimed into the instrument. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embouchure

Answer (score 3):

The direction of your airstream influences the octave produced by the flute.  For low notes, you need to aim the airstream down, and for high notes you need to aim the airsream up.  You are achieving this same effect by tilting the flute inwards- you are aiming the airstream up relative to the lip plate by moving the flute.

The change in direction is small, and will require practice to get it right.  Practice in front of a mirror, and when playing low notes, imagine that you are blowing towards the bottom of your face in the mirror.  When playing high notes, imagine that you are blowing towards your forehead in the mirror.  With time, you will develop the control necessary to do it without having to think about it.

Answer (score 1):

Turning the flute in is your way of angling the air stream from your lips downward more steeply into the embouchure hole.  But try instead using your lips to do that.  Let the upper lip loosen up so it goes out further from your teeth, and/or pull your lower lip inwards, possibly moving the flute downward a little on your chin.